# ESP32 drains LIFePO4 3.2V battery, any suggestions?

Tags: arduino, batteries, embedded, esp32, iot

I'm trying to build a smart scale using [this ESP32,](https://www.amazon.in/Allianztec-ESP-WROOM-32-Development-Microcontroller-Integrated/dp/B08VJ2CKG1) which is connected to a HX-711 amplifier + load-cell. It's also connected to an HC-12 RF communication sensor.

Here are pictures of my setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrxtf.jpg

The purpose of this device is to measure weight changes and transmit the current weight to a distance device using the RF sensor.

No need for Wifi or Bluetooth on this board.

The problem is that this device should be wireless, and the batteries are getting drained in a couple of days at best, and I'm kind of helpless at the moment.

I went down to take weight measurements every 8 hours, and during those 8 hours I'm putting my ESP32 into a hibernation mode which should be the best one for battery consumption saving, but that also doesn't help.

I started to think that the ESP32 is not meant for this assignment and that maybe there's a better alternative board that might do the job and keep the battery alive for a few weeks/months instead of a couple of days.

Can anybody recommend a different board, or maybe suggest what else can I do to make this circuit run without draining in a couple of days?

As mentioned, I do not need the Wifi and Bluetooth, and mainly using the ESP32 due to its deep-sleep/hibernation mode.

I'll also add the main parts of my code, maybe the problem is there:

```C
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_sleep.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "HX711.h"

const int LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN = 22;
const int LOADCELL_SCK_PIN = 23;

HX711 scale;

int currentWeight = 0;
int previousWeight = -100;

uint64_t TIME_TO_SLEEP = 60*60*8;
#define uS_TO_S_FACTOR 1000000ull

void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  btStop();
  rfSetup();
  weightSetup();
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  weightLoop();
  delay(2000);
  esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_PERIPH,   ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
  esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_SLOW_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
  esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_FAST_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
  esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_XTAL,         ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);

  esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
  delay(1000);
}

void weightSetup() {
  scale.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
  scale.set_scale(173.90393);
}

void weightLoop() {
  scale.power_up();
  currentWeight = (scale.get_units());
  delay(1000);
  scale.power_down();
  sendWeightToHub(currentWeight);
}

void rfSetup() {
  HC12.begin(BUED);
}

void sendWeightToHub(int newWeight) {
  HC12.write(String(newWeight).c_str());
}
```

Last thing - When I check the current in the multimeter the current - I get 0.01 (out of 20mA) when sleeping, and up to 0.05 (again, out of 20mA) when awake. That doesn't add up to draining the battery in 2 days though, so I guess I did something wrong there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your current measurement description is a little confusing - please update with correct values using units.  Also please provide the mAh rating of your battery. The ESP32 should absolutely be sufficient for this project, but you may not be optimizing it perfectly. Also be aware that different DEV boards can reach lower deep sleep currents, so your specific board may be the wrong one for the job.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the fast response @InBedded16.
I'm kind of new to this area, and learning as I go, so I'm not too familiar with all the terms and methods.
That being said, when connecting the circuit to the multimeter, and setting the multimeter to 20mA, I can see in sleep mode a value of 0.01, and when it measures and communicate via RF, it peeks up to 0.05 for about 10 seconds.
The battery I'm using has the number of 18650, which according to the web should have 1800mAh: https://www.batteryspace.com/LiFePO4-18650-Rechargeable-Cell-3.2V-1800-mAh.aspx, is there a way to measure it?

Comment: Since you wrote that the board seems to be a good fit for that project, the only variable that is still puzzling to me is the battery.
Would love to get a feedback and improvements suggestions, and an advice on which batteries will work the best for this kind of project.
Regarding the board itself - I attached a link to the exact board I'm using at the top of the post. are there any other types of esp32 that might be better for that matter?

Comment: You do not write how do you know that the LiFePO4 cell is empty. The voltage curve is very flat. Normally you use the cell only between 20 and 90%, this means between 3.23V and 3.33V. Link: https://footprinthero.com/lifepo4-battery-voltage-charts (under the headline "3.2V LiFePO4 Cell Voltage Chart")  (1800mAh/10mA)/24h = 7.5 days if you use the full capacity. 5.25 Days if you use only 70%.

Comment: @MikroPower I'm actually not 100% sure if I'm doing it right. but I do get an indication.
So I'm connecting the multimeter to the battery's + and -, every few hours, and I noticed the battery dropped from 3.28v to around 2.5v, after just 24 hours. which is the lower limit of that battery before it's dead for all I know. 
Plus, the RF signals stopped working about that time as well, I'm guessing it didn't have enough power to send it since the battery was too low, but again - I'm not too familiar with it to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Don't allow the cell voltage to go below 2.7V if you want it to last longer. Even better, keep it between 3.2V and 3.4V for the longest life or don't go beyond 3.0V and 3.55V during discharge and charge.

Comment: Thanks @EdinFifić. 
The problem is that it goes below 3.0V after just a few hours :(
With this spec and code, I wonder what's causing this rapid power loss.. Can't figure it out so far..

Comment: Where did you buy the battery/cell? Is it new?

Comment: I suspect 2 things: 1.) your cell at 3.28V is only 40% full;  2.) your cell may be old or have 10% of actual maximum capacity (cheap Chinese crap).

Comment: @EdinFifić I bought it in a store near my house, actually I have doubts about that store, but to be honest I also tried 3 AA batteries from well known companies in my country and they did very bad as well (less than 2 days).
can you recommend a decent battery that can work on a project like that, and that I can order from Amazon for example?

Comment: I know in my country (Bosnia) that the 18650 cells in Chinese stores and elsewhere costing about $1.50-$2.00 are of fake capacities, definitely having no more than 500-600mAh, and they are marked as 4800-6800mAh while such capacities at that size don't exist (largest possible is 3600mAh) and you get their ACTUAL capacity by taking one zero out (so they "only" exaggerated about 10 times, a small lie ;D ). An actual brand name 2500mAh cell here will cost about $6. The link you provided has them for less than $5 but they're actually LiFePO4 and not Li-Ion.

Comment: If you provide a picture of your cell with its markings, we might be able to determine more, if there is anything more than 18650 on it. You should also post pictures and wiring diagram of your setup, as well as where did you measure the current in your circuit. Right now we are blind to your setup, so to speak.

Comment: Ok, I'll start by providing an image of my battery:
[My battery](https://imgur.com/a/OR3dPeI)

Comment: Ok @EdinFifić you should now be able to see all the images of my circuit as well, all in this link: https://imgur.com/a/OR3dPeI
So there's the circuit, the battery image and the code, I gave everything I have :)
I'm sorry I don't have a diagram but as I mentioned I'm a fresh beginner so I'm not too organized unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, I saw them all. The battery looks suspicious, it might be a Chinese joke, it has "SLNY" instead of "SONY" for example, I might be wrong. It's actual capacity could be as low as 180mAh. The power capacity is indicated as 5.76Wh which is 5.76W / 3.2V = 1800mAh. The way to test it to charge it with no more than 900mA current until it reaches 3.65V. After you let it rest overnight without charge and without load, it should be 3.40V in the morning if 100% full. Then you load it with constant current of 360mA or about 9Ω resistor and see how long it takes until it reaches 3.20V.

Comment: It should be 3.20V after you disconnect the test load. If it's above, load it a bit more, disconnect load and then check its voltage after a little bit to make sure it's 3.20V, which means it's 20% full. At this point you would have discharged 80% of its capacity. For 1800mAh capacity, that's 0.8 x 1800 = 1440mAh which at 360mA load (20%  or 1/5 of the amp-hour rating) should have taken about 4 hours. If it takes significantly less time to discharge at that current, it's a bad or low capacity battery. Look at the prices of brand name cells in your area, then look at how much you've paid for it

Comment: You will get approximately what you paid for it.  ;-)

Comment: Great, I follow your instructions. thank you so much for your kind help @EdinFifić!

Answer (score 1):

First, 18650 is not LIFePO4 battery as you mentioned in your post title, it is Li-ion battery, with nominal voltage of 3.7V, and max charge-up voltage of 4.2v, cut-off voltage at about 2.5V.

Secondly, your board is not designed for battery operation, if the product image you show matched your actual board, the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) regulator on the board has a very high Quiescent Current of 5mA, and 1.1V dropout voltage. The board also has power LED that is constant On (and likely consumed 1.5-2mA constantly) even during sleep mode, so the current consumption at the deep sleep is likely 6.5-7mA. The high dropout voltage also means that even if your battery is fully charged at 4.2V, with high dropout voltage of 1.1V across the regulator, it will only barely able to output 4.2-1.1=3.1V instead of regulated 3.3V, the ESP32 will probably brown-out at about 3.0V, plus the high leakage current and PWR LED, and a questionable battery, it simply barely work for a while.

Get an ESP32 board that is designed for battery operation, both Adafruit and SparkFun have boards designed for battery operation, so is China's DFRobot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed information @hcheung! It makes a lot of sense, and I will certainly check out the boards you suggested.
I also had doubts about the battery, but the guy at the store said it's LIFePO4 and I'm not too much of an expert so I followed what he said...

May I ask what battery would you recommend me to use for those boards and code?

Comment: Hmmmm, I'd say "one that's not fake" lol

Answer (score 0):

Besides what hcheung said,

> I do not need the Wifi and Bluetooth, and mainly using the esp32 due to its deep-sleep/Hibernation mode.

Then why use ESP32? There are many other microcontrollers that can do what you need, for example STM32 or one of the Arduinos. One of the problems with ESP32 is that the sleep mode with RAM retention is quite power-hungry compared to other micros, and the deep sleep loses RAM so you have to reboot it, which also uses quite a lot of energy.

You would need to be careful about picking a micro and read the fine print on sleep modes if you were running it on a coin cell. But for a 18650, pretty much any micro with a RAM retention sleep mode will do the trick. Ironically, the ESP32 is one of the few that won't work well, because its light sleep mode with RAM retention uses 800µA, whereas most micros will use a couple µA or less.

I was about to recommend Raspberry Pi Pico because it has a buck boost converter which is nice to have when running on battery, but its sleep current is 180µA which is quite high too.

If you want to run from a 18650 and not bother with a buck-boost converter, using a 3V3 LDO will give 3V3 when it is fully charged, dropping to a bit lower than 3V when it is close to discharged. So...

HX711 is specified to run on 2.7V minimum. For micros, most STM32 M0 will run down to 2V, 8-bit AVR runs down to less than 2V if you run it at 4MHz, so it's fine. You don't need a high power micro like ESP32 to measure a weight and transmit it.

The RF module will probably need more, but perhaps you can replace the LDO with a lower dropout one.

So I'd suggest changing the micro, and if possible using parts that can run on the battery voltage directly, or using a 3V3 LDO and parts that will tolerate voltage drop down to 3V.

Comment: Great points @bobflux. thank you very much for the detailed and helpfull response as well. I'm looking for the right micro right now, according to the answers I got here so far.
Regarding the battery, I'm not sure I want to use this 18650 battery, I got some recommendations above on better alternatives so I might try those, but if you also have a recommendation for a battery that might fit this project, I would love to hear about it. Thanks again!